# Setting with checkbox and number slider, reduce it to only a slider

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, checkboxes, sliders

I have to implement a number range slider for a *maximum width* parameter. For example the lowest slider value is 500 and for the highest I set it to a reasonable value of 3.000.

First the user chooses if he wants to set a value or not. I'm thinking of using a checkbox that enables/disables the slider. If the user didn't want to set a value then the result is there is no maximum width, which is the same as saying the maximum width is infinite.

**My question**: is there any way to avoid the use of the checkbox? A way could be to set a really high value in the slider (for example 10.000). But this would make the slider hard to use for real values.

Answer (score 1):

If the user wants to set a value, with a value range between 500-3000, it can be challenging to navigate to a precise value (especially trying to drag within a mobile touch environment). In most cases, input boxes will be more efficient so it's something that you may consider include as part of the UI or even ditch the range slider in favor of the inputs.

If precise width does not matter, maybe consider a tiered slider that contains milestones and have the max to be unlimited. [image]

Comment: Thank you :) Ill include an input as well. Very interesting the milestones you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this could work:

Display the minimum value in a disabled text input and the maximum with 3000+(indicating more than 3k) value.

[image: Slider]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion :) I'm not convinced about including two inputs where one is disabled. But I like the idea of indicating the minimum value and the maximum which would go from 2999 to 3000+ or no limit or similar.